# def get_data command not being recognized in python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

```
File "Predicting_stock", line 9
    def get_data(HistoricalQuotes.csv):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is straightforward: when you define a function, the parameters you declare must be simple names, such as `input_file`.  You tried to specify a compound name, as if you are trying to create a variable `HistoricalQuotes` with an attribute `csv`.  This is *not* how you make such a variable.

It appears that you *might* be trying to do something with a file named `HistoricalQuotes.csv`.  If so, this is not at all the proper syntax.  Work through a tutorial on file handling to see the range of applications and sample code for this.  In your case, it might be something such as

```
def get_data():
    with open("HistoricalQuotes.csv", `r`):
        # Here is where you read the data from the file you just opened.
```